# Loop over the explicit specializations of a class template

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Is there a way in C++98/03 to loop over all explicit specializations defined for a class template? How about C++11/14?

P.S. By loop, I mean compile-time looping of course (i.e. using recursive templates).

Comment: Seems like that would require some form of introspection, which C++ is (currently) not very capable of

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: I'm trying to create a variant type akin to boost::variant with the difference that consumers are allowed to add more types to the variant non-intrusively i.e. without having to change the variant definition. I was hoping to achieve this by requiring a specialization of some class template for every new type that provides info about the new type, and have the equivalent of boost::apply_visitor() loop over those specializations. I just realized that that won't be possible even if this functionality is allowed in C++, because the specializations would be in different translation units any way.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://goo.gl/6ODTFj) can be of use. The any_type class implements something like boost::variant without the restriction of supplying which types can be held.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such mechanism in the C++ standard.

Such a thing can be done manually, but the compiler will not help you.

While there is effort undergoing to do reflection, it is ongoing, and what you describe is not any of its currently listed goals.

Compilers do parse C++ files and in effect do what you are requesting, and clang for one compiles C++ into an intermediate representation, so you could write a consumer of that intermediate representation if you really needed what you are describing.